# When we used redis and using lazy loading in Hibernate,we might face exceptions,saying there is no session,ebean cache issue with @ManyToMany relation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, redis, jpql

while using lazy loading in Hibernate, we might face exceptions, saying there is no session.

Answer (score 0):

first add it in application.properties

```
          spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
          spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
          spring.cache.type=redis
          spring.redis.host=localhost
          spring.redis.port=6379
          spring.cache.cache-names=anyName
          spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=60000
          spring.cache.redis.key-prefix=your project name or anyName
```

then add it in your Model class

```
          @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```